# Linq2Sql and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have that tables schema

[image]

via linq2Sql, I generate a query:

```
var types = (from d in TabD
             where d.SomeID == myID
             group d by d.TabC.TabB.TabA into g
             select g.Key);
```

which generates that query

```
SELECT Distinct1.ID, Distinct1.Name
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ss.ID, ss.Name
        FROM TabD AS d
        INNER JOIN TabC AS c ON d.TabC_ID = c.ID
        INNER JOIN TabB AS b ON c.TabB_ID = b.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TabA AS a ON b.TabA_ID = a.ID
        WHERE sg.SomeID = 1
     ) AS Distinct1
```

which works, but why there is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: It seems that are missing parts in this query. Where are `ss` and `sg` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You get LEFT JOIN whenever the foreign key on a table is nullable. If your database defines TabA_ID as `TabA_ID int NULL` it means TabB reference to TabA is not enforced.

Since it is not enforced based on your schema LINQ2SQL generates a LEFT join.

Hope this helps